# Issue Using a .txt File to Populate a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning to use MySQL Workbench and am having trouble importing data. I have created a database, a schema, and a table. The table has three columns. I have been using the following query to try to populate the table using a .txt file. The file uses new lines to separate rows and two spaces to separate columns.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\toImport.txt'
INTO TABLE schema.table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
LINES STARTING BY '\n';
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error Code: 2. File 'C:UsersNickDesktoptoImport.txt' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? This is my first go at learning SQL so apologies if this is quite basic. Thanks!

Comment: Try "\\" or "/" as directory separator. I don't remember what's correct for windows.

Comment: You should add one more backslash as an escape in your code `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\toImport.txt'`

Comment: "On Windows, specify backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html - So both '\\' and '/' should work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, using "/" allowed the script to execute. However, using "\" did not work.

Once I removed a column from the table, all data imported perfectly.

Thanks for the help!